# Deleting underline in URL's [text-decoration: none; doesn't work]

Tags: html, css

I want to delete underline. I have already put `text-decoration: none;`. However it doesn't work. Here is a [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/96sf8/1).

HTML

```
<a href="./index.php?sign_in=1">
    <div id="signup_button">
        Sign up
    </div>
</a>
```

CSS

```
#signup_button {
    position: relative;
    max-width: 206px;
    min-height: 20px;
    max-height: 40px;
    margin: auto;
    margin-top: 10px;
    padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
    background-color: #0096cc;
    text-align: center;
    color:#fff;
    font: 35px/1 "Impact";
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

Comment: You need to apply `text-decoration: none` to a tag see this demo http://jsfiddle.net/96sf8/2/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`text-decoration` belongs to the "a" tag, but you can also get rid of the div.

If you set the display:block on the a, you have the same effect

```
<a href="./index.php?sign_in=1" class="signup_button">Sign up</a>
```

now looks exactly the same as

```
<a href="./index.php?sign_in=1">
  <div class="signup_button">
    Sign up
  </div>
</a>
```

using

```
.signup_button {
  position: relative;
  max-width: 206px;
  min-height: 20px;
  max-height: 40px;
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: 10px;
  padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
  background-color: #0096cc;
  text-align: center;
  color:#fff;
  font: 35px/1 "Impact";
  display:block;
}
a {
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```css
.signup_button {
  position: relative;
  max-width: 206px;
  min-height: 20px;
  max-height: 40px;
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: 10px;
  padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
  background-color: #0096cc;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
  font: 35px/1"Impact";
  display: block;
}
a {
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<a href="./index.php?sign_in=1" class="signup_button">Sign up</a>
<p><hr /></p>
<a href="./index.php?sign_in=1">
  <div class="signup_button">
    Sign up
  </div>
</a>
```

Answer (score 7):

Set

```
a {
    text-decoration:none;
}
```

before your style. The underline is coming from there.

Comment: Yes it is correct, but not the full story. No need to wrap a link in a div or a div in a link (not proper html) to style it

Answer (score 3):

You need to set `text-decoration: none` on the `a` element not the `div` inside it.

Also, it's not good practice to put block level elements like `divs` inside of inline elements like `anchors`.  You should just apply all the `#signup_button` styles directly to the `a` and get rid of the `div`.

Answer (score 2):

You should not place a DIV inside of an A tag. I did some changes which will make it work.

HTML

```
<div id="signup_button_container">
  <a id="signup_button" href="./index.php?sign_in=1">
    Sign up
  </a>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#signup_button_container {
  text-align: center;
}

#signup_button {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    max-width: 206px;
    min-height: 20px;
    max-height: 40px;
    margin: auto;
    margin-top: 10px;
    padding: 10px 30px;
    background-color: #0096cc;
    color:#fff;
    font: 35px/1 "Impact";
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/96sf8/4/

Comment: No need for the div at all